# Remote Desktop Licensing Mode is not configured.

Tags: azure

I am just starting out learning Azure. I have set up a few Subscriptions, each with 1 VM, storage etc. When using RDP to log in, after 2 users log in, the 3rd gets the "you have to log some one else off etc". So I added the Remote Desktop Services role. Now any number of users can log in. However, now I get the "Remote Desktop Licensing Mode is not configured.Remote Desktop Services will stop in 119 days." It says to use the Connection Broker service etc which I don't know about.  When talking to MS before starting with Azure, they confirmed that no CAL's were required- just get a Pay-As-You-Go subscription and away you go with as many users as you want. What exactly do I need to do?  I don't have an Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

The CAL statement you received concerns things like Azure's Active Directory product, not Terminal Services, which has its own licensing terms that are separate from Windows Server CALs used in a Domain Join situation.

The licensing page on the Windows Azure website is the canonical source ( https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/ )

> **Can service providers build a cloud-based service on Azure using session-based hosting through RDS (Remote Desktop Services, formerly known as Terminal Services)?**
>   Yes, service providers can offer hosted solutions through RDS running on Azure as long as they obtained RDS SALs (Subscriber Access Licenses) through a Microsoft Services Provider License Agreement (SPLA) reseller.

This blog posting from 2013 makes this clear: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luispanzano/archive/2013/07/15/remote-desktop-services-are-now-allowed-on-windows-azure.aspx

> To enable more than 2 simultaneous sessions you will need to purchase RDS Subscriber Access Licenses (SALs) through the Microsoft Services Provider Licensing Agreement (SPLA) for each user or device that will access your solution on Windows Azure. SPLA is separate from an Azure agreement and is contracted through an authorized SPLA reseller.

In conclusion: give Microsoft more money.

Comment: Thanks. I see that I need SAL's for each user now. An additional question-  our application is a MS Access database and uses the free Access 2007 Runtime for our customers. Is there going to be ANOTHER CAL required for using the free runtime in a hosted environment? I have heard both yes and no so far.

Comment: There are no SAL or CAL licenses for the Access runtime. It is freely redistributable.

Comment: @jhuffster You might want to consider making your application a web-app using SQL Server Express, that way you won't need any CALs or SALs at all, and SQL Server Express is free.